# ActionController::UrlGenerationError: error No routes matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I get the below error ActionController::UrlGenerationError.

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"/accounts/100", :controller=>"accounts"}
```

Below is my code which throws this error.

```
  it "can find an account" do
  Account.should_receive(:find, with: {id: 2055, authorization: @auth}

  get "/accounts/100", nil, {"AUTH_TOKEN" => @auth}

  hashed_response = {
    "@type" => "test",
    "createdAt" => "2014-07-24T15:26:49",
    "description" => "Something about test",
    "disabled" => false
  }
  expect(response.status).to eq 200    
  expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);

end
```

I did a google on this and came to know that there is no routes defined for this. Below is my `config/routes.rb` file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   resources :accounts do
      resources :holders
   end
end
```

Comment: Why `100` is hard coded?

Comment: Do a `rake routes` and you can see the routes pattern available for the application.

Answer (score 7):

I presume this error is coming from a controller spec? If so, you simply use a symbol representing the action you want to call, not the URL itself.

eg. this is a show action, so you would use:

`get :show, id: 100`

Comment: yes, so you are testing a controller action with a controller spec. Also, you're stubbing the account with the wrong ID, and you have a syntax error on the same line.

Comment: and you're stubbing the lookup of account ID 2055

Comment: But my show method yeilds me html instead of json which i need to compare.

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq(hashed_response.to_json);
           
           expected: "{\"@type\":\"test\",\"createdAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58.198\",\"createdBy\":2,\"updatedAt\":\"2014-08-07T14:31:58.247\",\"updatedBy\":2,\"accountid\":2055,\"name\":\"test\",\"description\":\"Something about test\",\"disabled\":false}"
                got: "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/login\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"

Comment: your action requires authentication, and you are not authenticating in the test. You're also not requesting JSON so I would be surprised if you got JSON back.

Comment: Add authentication  - ` before(:each) do
    user = double('user')
    request.env['warden'].stub :authenticate! => user
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_user) { user }

  end`